# Tar files convert in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tar

I have the following problem: i dont have Zipfiles. I have tar files. Can anyone help me please to change the code to tar files?

```
import glob
import os
from zipfile import ZipFile

zipfiles = [os.path.basename(x) for x in glob.glob(r'./*.zip')]

for zipfile in zipfiles:
    new_dirname = zipfile.replace('.bsw.', '_').replace('.zip', '')
    try:
        os.mkdir(f'output/{new_dirname}')
    except:
        print(f'output/{new_dirname} already exists')
    try:
        os.mkdir(f'output/{new_dirname}/subdir')
    except:
        print(f'output/{new_dirname}/subdir already exists')

    with ZipFile(f'./{zipfile}') as zipObject:
        zipObject.extractall(path=f'output/{new_dirname}/subdir')
```

Comment: "I have the following problem: How do I extract a tar file into this existing code." What do you mean by "into"? "Unfortunately it doesn't find any tar files" Why should it? What tar files do you think are there, and why do you think they are there? Where the code says `tarfile.open('C:/Data/ODX/swfkbin/')`, exactly what do you expect this to mean? What file do you think should be opened, and why? And what does that have to do with the `for zipfile in zipfiles:` loop?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I have 90 tar files. For this I need 90 new folders with the name from the tar files without .bin. A subfolder called “full” must be created in each file. The tar file should then be unpacked into the respective folder.

Comment: What exactly is the problem here? I asked a question here and have now revised it. Nevertheless, it is rated poorly. What don't you understand? I simply have to read in several files, hence a loop. I'm new to Python and am teaching myself everything... mistakes sometimes happen.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
zipfiles = [os.path.basename(x) for x in glob.glob('C:/Data/ODX/swfkbin/*')]

for zipfile in zipfiles:
    new_dirname = zipfile.replace('.bin.', '_')
    #try:
    os.mkdir(f'output/{new_dirname}')
    #except:
    print(f'output/{new_dirname} already exists')
    #try:
    os.mkdir(f'output/{new_dirname}/full')
    #except:
    print(f'output/{new_dirname}/subdir already exists')
    #try:
    # your tar file
    tarfile = "your_tar_file_path"
    file = tarfile.open(tarfile)
    file.extractall('output/{new_dirname}/full')
    file.close()
    #except:
    print ("Not possible to extract")
```

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer and explain how it solves OP's problem.

Answer (score 2):

I would assume that is due to the fact that you do not pass the zipfile you're iterating over to `tarfile.open()`.

```py
zipfiles = [os.path.basename(x) for x in glob.glob('C:/Data/ODX/swfkbin/*')]

for zipfile in zipfiles:
    new_dirname = zipfile.replace('.bin.', '_')
    #try:
    os.mkdir(f'output/{new_dirname}')
    #except:
    print(f'output/{new_dirname} already exists')
    #try:
    os.mkdir(f'output/{new_dirname}/full')
    #except:
    print(f'output/{new_dirname}/subdir already exists')
    #try:
    file = tarfile.open(zipfile)
    file.extractall('output/{new_dirname}/full')
    file.close()
    #except:
    print ("Not possible to extract")
```

As a sidenode a more pythonic way would be to use a context manager when calling `tarfile.open()` instead of explicitly closing it.

```py
with tarfile.open(zipfile, 'r:*') as file:
    file.extractall('output/{new_dirname}/full')
```

Comment: i get following error:  with tarfile.open(tarfiles, 'r:*') as tar:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'open' did you know what to do?

Comment: I am guessing you changed your code from the above and somewhere did something along the lines of `tarfile = xxxx` (probably by changing the line `for zipfile in zipfiles` to `for tarfile in tarfiles` judging from your minisample). That effectively overwrites your own `import tarfile`. Could that be? If so, just chabge the name of the filea youre iterating over.